# How do you join a for loop output in a string separated by comma?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a for loop that goes through a dictionary and then stores the value in a list however right now, it stores each one separately.

it creates something like this:

```
example-123456
example-789012
```

I want the format to be:

```
[['example-123456'], ['example-789012']]
```

but i can't seem to figure it out. My code looks like this:

```
    for i in response:
        for k in i['Output']:
            for key, value in k.items():
                if key == 'example-keys':
                    example_grp = []
                    example_grp.append(value)
                    join_values = ",".join(map(str,example_grp))
                    print(join_values)
```

The example output I'm working with looks like this:

```
{
    'FilleraValue': 'filler:12345678910:filler/filler/filler',
    'AValue': 'sample-a-value',
    'Output': [{
        'BValue': 'b-b-b-value',
        'example-keys': 'example-123456'
    }, {
        'BValue': 'c-c-c-value',
        'example-keys': 'example-789012'
    }]
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: As much as possible something like this `['example-123456', 'example-789012']`

Comment: Move `example_grp = []` before the innerst for loop, and unindent `join_values = …` and `print(join_values)` by two levels.

Comment: @Programmer, I don't think so, because the line above includes the ```join_values = ",".join(map(str,example_grp))```,

Comment: @Programmer I see what you mean, the join_values  line and the next line should be outdented to match the top level for loop

Comment: omg so sorry, i just realized that i out the wrong expected output there. I wanted to go with `['example-123456'], ['example-789012']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is more going on in your actual problem than in your question either of these should produce the result you seek:

given input as:

```
response = [
    {
        'FilleraValue': 'filler:12345678910:filler/filler/filler',
        'AValue': 'sample-a-value',
        'Output': [
            {
                'BValue': 'b-b-b-value',
                'example-keys': 'example-123456'
            }, {
                'BValue': 'c-c-c-value',
                'example-keys': 'example-789012'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

option 1:

```
results = []
for i in response:
    for k in i['Output']:
        results.append(k["example-keys"])
print(results)
```

option 2:

```
results = [k["example-keys"] for i in response for k in i['Output']]
print(results)
```

Both options produce:

```
['example-123456', 'example-789012']
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want do this:

```
for i in response:
    for k in i['Output']:
        for key, value in k.items():
            if key == 'example-keys':
                example_grp = []
                example_grp.append(value)
print(f"[{", ".join(map(str,example_grp))} ]")
```